# placeholder workaround for IE using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

IE does not support placeholders for input elements. I am trying to use jquery workaround

What I want is on page load the field value sld get initialized. I am able to do on field focus. for eg. this works

```
  // ThiS Works on focus, "Email" is shown in text box
$(function() {
  $("#login_email").focus(function()
  {
      if ($(this).val() == "")
      {
          $(this).val("Email");
      }
  });
});

  // I hoped that this will intialize on page load. But this does not work ???
  // This does not work

$(function() {
  $("#login_email").val("Email");
});
```

How can I fix this?

Why does not option two work but option 1 work? What is the difference??

Comment: You can try this library: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Comment: How about just combining the two handlers and using the jQuery chaining.  `$("#login_email").focus(function(){...}).val("Email");`

Comment: Try one of the polyfill scripts listed here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills -- there are several placeholder scripts to try.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest this approach

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $("#login_email").val($("#login_email").attr("placeholder"));

    $("#login_email").on("focus", function() {
      var elem = $(this);
      if (elem.val() == "") {
          elem.val(elem.attr("placeholder"));
      } else if(elem.val() == elem.attr("placeholder")) {
          elem.val("");
      }
    });

    $("#login_email").on("blur", function() {
      var elem = $(this);
      if (elem.val() == "") {
          elem.val(elem.attr("placeholder"));
      }
    });
});
```

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="login_email" placeholder="Email">
```

This way, it is more reusable.
See JsFiddle for more details: http://jsfiddle.net/SUdbs/

Comment: I was thinking his problem might be that his js is loading before the element is created (but I don't know that.) If so, the use of .on() should help him solve his problem.

Comment: @o_O, I think you might be right. However, .on is also executed before its full loaded/initialized. Is there any other event that I can use????

Comment: You can use the old syntax if you prefer, like: $("#login_email").focus(function() {...}); $("#login_email").blur(function() {...});

Comment: The .on() would be ok but it is only available for events (click, focus, blur, etc) so you can't use .on() for the one I had with $(this).val("Email") since there is no .on() for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".#login_email").val("Email")
    .focus(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "Email"){
            $(this).val("");
        }
    })
    .blur(function(){
        if($(this).val().length == 0){
            $(this).val("Email");
        }
    });
```

This will give you a placeholder-like input. I like how placeholder fades out on focused instead of disappearing, but for sake of cutting down a lot on code bloat, this might be good for you.

Comment: as per your comment above, .val("Email") gets executed before the element is fully loaded. Hence I added a 50ms timeout. But thats not good either.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
  $("#login_email, #login_password").blur(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.val() == '') {
      input.addClass("placeholder");
      input.val(input.attr("placeholder"));
    }
  })
  // This is needed at the time of page load. There is
  // potential race condition happening here.
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#login_email, #login_password").each(function() {
      var input = $(this);
      if (input.val() == '') {
        input.addClass("placeholder");
        input.val(input.attr("placeholder"));
      }
    })
  }, 50);
```

Comment: I would appreciate if somebody could help me remove setTimeout